# React-leaflet - add/remove style to CircleMarker on click

Tags: react-leaflet

I am working with react-leaflet to show some data points as circles on a map. I am trying to add a click function to `<CircleMarker>` so when a circle is clicked, it will add a className "active" and when another circle is clicked, it will remove the "active" class from the previously clicked circle and add the "active" class to the newly clicked circle.

I have a handleClick function that gets the clicked element and setState on the "selected" property with that element. I thought I could just do something like `className={ selected.id === data.id ? "active" : "inactive" }` for each `<CircleMarker>`, but it is not switching to the "active" class but stays "inactive" on every click. I checked my css and "active" class works, and the click function is properly firing. Please help!! Here is the simplified version of my code:

```
class MapComponent extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          selected: {}
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
      }

      handleClick(data, e) {
        this.setState({ selected: data })
      }

      render(){
        const { myData } = this.props;
        const { selected } = this.state;

        return (     
          <div>  
            <Map center="xxxxx" zoom=11>
              <TileLayer url="xxxxx" attribution="xxxxx" />
              {
                myData && myData.values.map(data => {
                  return (
                    <CircleMarker
                      className={ selected.id === data.id ? "active" : "inactive" }
                      key={ data.id }
                      center={ new L.latLng(data.latitude, data.longitude) } 
                      radius=10
                      color="red"
                      value={ data.id }
                      onClick={ (e) => this.handleCircleClick(data, e) }
                    > 
                    </CircleMarker>
                  )
                })
              }
            </Map>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out. It's not so pretty, but I had to manipulate the `DOMTokenList` manually inside my `handleClick()` method, using something like `event.target._path.classList.replace()`:

```
handleClick(data, e) {
    this.setState({ selected: data })

    if(e.target._path.classList.contains("inactive")){
        e.target._path.classList.replace("inactive", "active")
        $(event.target).siblings().removeClass("active")
        $(event.target).siblings().addClass("inactive")
    } 
}
```

I still don't know why I can't just change the className by doing `className={ selected.id === data.id ? "active" : "inactive" }` on the react-leaflet's `<CircleMarker>` component though.